# Тестирование приложения для ios

Tags: ios, apple, тестирование

Подскажите, я дописал приложение для яблока и вот хотел бы протестировать его на реальном устройстве. Вопрос: можно ли как-то его протестировать, не платя 99$, а заплатить их после того, как закончится тестирование?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При наличии jailbreak'a на аппарате это возможно.
Также потребуется скорректировать xCode.

Comment: А без jailbreak'a никак? Просто яблоко не моё, и хозяйка не очень хочет его ломать.

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Увы, мне, такой способ не известен.

Comment: @Zatoichy ок, спасибо за столь быстрый ответ

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - попросить товарища, имеющего учетку разработчика сделать Adhoc-сборку, или установить приложение сразу на девайс по кабелю из xCode.

Если товарищ сильно занят, то пусть даст вам доступ к своему аккаунту, чтобы вы сами все это сделали.

С Test Flight не стоит возиться, если потом вы сами будете заводить свою учетку.